# Python reportlab generates large files when I add jpeg

Tags: python, image, pdf, jpeg, reportlab

I try to generate pdf filled up with jpeg images, but even when I add only one **176 kB** (1142 × 1713) image, I get **2.5 mB** pdf. When I open this pdf in Photoshop, I see that this is the same jpeg on a canvas, with the same size. Looks like reportlab doesn't do any compression for jpeg or something. There's no any information about it in the documentation. 
Here's my code:

```
...
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.utils import ImageReader
from reportlab.lib.units import mm
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open('/Users/dimabogdan/Downloads/3edbc3086ccadcae8c59a702a4e03020.jpg')
# <PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=1142x1713 at 0x10A74BE48>
img = ImageReader(img)
c = canvas.Canvas('pdf.pdf', pagesize=(320*mm, 470*mm))
c.drawImage(img, x=0, y=0, height=152*mm, width=102*mm)
c.save()
...
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Try running `pdfimages YOURFILE.pdf` and see what is actually in the PDF it generates. It is part of the `Poppler` package.

Comment: @MarkSetchell  
I just tried it and got **5mB .ppm** image.
Tried to search "ppm reportlab" on google and github, but can't find anything relevant

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this same issue, and for anyone still having this problem the code:

```
img = ImageReader(img)
c.drawImage(img, x=0, y=0, height=152*mm, width=102*mm)
```

creates a PDF with uncompressed image data, however you can compress the image with jpeg into a temporary buffer and feed it to reportlab and it will save it compressed, like so:

```
with BytesIO() as img_jpg: # we create a new BytesIO object, don't forget 'from io import BytesIO'
    img.save(img_jpg, format='jpeg') # img is the image from Image.open, we save it to the buffer
    img_jpg.seek(0) # reset the buffer position

    img_ = ImageReader(img_jpg) # create ImageReader from buffer
    c.drawImage(img, x=0, y=0, height=152*mm, width=102*mm) # draw compressed jpeg to PDF
```

Your sample code should work fine, since you are feeding a jpeg image too, but it doesn't...